# Why cant I pass dictionary from flask to html template?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to run the following code:

```
@app.route("/invoice", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def inv():
    dic = {
        'iname': [],
        'iemail': []
    }

    if request.method == "POST":
        iname = str(request.form["Iname"])
        iemail = str(request.form["Iemail"])

        dic['iname'].append(iname)
        dic['iemail'].append(iemail)

        return redirect(url_for("invoicepdf", dic=dic))
    else:
        return render_template("invoice.html")

@app.route("/<dic>")
def invoicepdf(dic):
    return f"hello {dic['iname']}"
```

It's showing me an error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I spend hours to find out what was the problem but couldn't fix it.. dictionary is very hard to do with web data. This is a simplified version of the code, there are more variables like address, phone, price, etc.

Comment: You are giving it to the wrong call (`redirect()`).

Comment: This is basically the same problem like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66787440/how-do-i-run-the-parent-function-in-flask/66817060#66817060 - there is no need for one view function to call another.

Comment: Can you elaborate it a bit more?? What do you mean here by wrong redirect?